# Nested Loop in r

Tags: r, nested-loops

I am having trouble writing an algo in r, in python this wouldnt be a big deal but r's syntax has thrown me off. 
I would like to set the first index of z and nums equal to eachother and put it into a list. 
Once in a list I would like to print the letter of a negative number.
Then i would like to print the numbers that correspond to j k l.

```
nums<-c(1.0, 3.0, -2, 8, -4, 4, 2, -3, 9, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 8, 2)
z<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p")
lets<-c(j,k,l)
for (i in nums){
for(j in z) {
}}
list=((a,1),(b,3),(c,-2),(d,8),(e,-4),(f,4),(g,2),(h,-3),(i,9),(j,1),(k,4),(l,2),(m,2),(n,1),(o,8),(p,2))

negative=c,e,h,
letters=1,4,2
```

Comment: `z[nums < 0]` and `nums[z %in% lets]` ? You're missing quotes around your letters

Comment: FYI you can also do `setNames(nums, z)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is (using your data):

```
df <- data.frame(z,nums, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

There all the letters and nums in

```
    > df
   z nums
1  a    1
2  b    3
3  c   -2
4  d    8
5  e   -4
6  f    4
7  g    2
8  h   -3
9  i    9
10 j    1
11 k    4
12 l    2
13 m    2
14 n    1
15 o    8
16 p    2
```

And then you can access what ever you want:

```
df$z[df$nums<0]
```

Results in:

```
[1] "c" "e" "h"
```

And to get the number for j,k,l you can use grepl:

```
df[grepl("[j,k,l]", df$z),]
   z nums
10 j    1
11 k    4
12 l    2
```

Then you have again a sub data frame or for just the numbers do:

```
df$nums[grepl("[j,k,l]", df$z)]
[1] 1 4 2
```

Comment: This is perfect. Can I loop through a list of c e h? What about if i wanted to test even numbers and print if it is true or false

Comment: you can store the sup data.frame with: 

`sub.data <- df[df$nums<0,]`

Which gives you, data frame just consisting of the rows for c,e and h

Comment: @WilliamBernard why would you loop ? all those manipulations are vectorised in R, no need for a loop

Comment: for learning sake, say i wanted to loop through j,k,l and print the numbers associated with the letters

Comment: Updated the answer, may this is want you want.

Comment: @WilliamBernard Using a loop is a very bad idea. You won't learn anything useful by using a loop where it is not necessary, on the contrary. Try and understand this answer instead. R is a modern programming language. Don't use 40-50 year old C- or Fortran-style constructs to solve such problems.